# Create custom directives for user?

Tags: php, laravel, templates, directive

I want user to be able to edit their own email contents on the Admin backend panel and user can use some directives such as:

- Date `{{date}}`
- Time `{{dime}}`
- Customer Name (get via db) `{{customer.name}}`
- Customer Number (get via db) `{{customer.phone}}`
- if statement `@if` `@else` `@endif`

So, for example user could do something like this in the `<textarea>`:

```
 @if(customer.name) Dear {{customer.name}} @endif
```

How do I create some custom directives in Laravel, any library I can use to ease development? Of course user is not allowed to use PHP code.

I know there is Laravel Blade but I am not sure that is safe to use for public users to edit contents and only allow customer directives only.

Comment: Are you asking how to make your own limited templating language?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes and allowable directives but maybe there are any plugin I can use?

Comment: [Smarty has advanced features where you can disable most things individually](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl)

Answer (score 0):

You can use different syntax than Blade, then translate it to Blade

```
@if(customer.name) Dear {{customer.name}} @endif
```

would become

```
#if[customer.name] Dear [[customer.name]] #endif
```

than create a function that replaces # with @ and so on.

Check this : [PHP Looping Template Engine - From Scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017582/php-looping-template-engine-from-scratch)